# Virtual Hostname Returning Default Localhost for Apache2 Instead of Specified Directory

Tags: php, apache, apache2, yii2-advanced-app

I've been having issues with setting up virtual hostnames for a yii2 advanced-app project I'm trying to get started on.

I set up the httpd-vhosts.conf for both a front end and a backend to be served. That setup looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName testcodetube.test
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCodeTube\frontend\web"
        
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCodeTube\frontend\web">
            # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
            RewriteEngine on
            # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
            RewriteRule . index.php

            # use index.php as index file
            DirectoryIndex index.php

            # ...other settings...
            # Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
            
            ## Apache 2.2
            # Order allow,deny
            # Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName studio.testcodetube.test
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCodeTube\backend\web"
        
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCodeTube\backend\web">
            # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
            RewriteEngine on
            # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
            RewriteRule . index.php

            # use index.php as index file
            DirectoryIndex index.php

            # ...other settings...
            # Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
            
            ## Apache 2.2
            # Order allow,deny
            # Allow from all
        </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

I also edited the hosts file which currently looks like this:

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.130.59 host.docker.internal
192.168.130.59 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
127.0.0.2 testcodetube.test
127.0.0.2 studio.testcodetube.test
```

So now the odd thing is, when I type in testcodetube.test or studio.testcodetube.test in the search bar, it redirects me to the default Windows localhost page (with all the greetings in multiple languages), instead of the directory I specified.

If I type in localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.2:8080 it serves the correct directory. Also, if I ping either testcodetube.test or studio.testcodetube.test I get a successful response back:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>ping testcodetube.test

Pinging testcodetube.test [127.0.0.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

I'm quite new to this so I could be completely wrong, but I'm quite confused as to how it would know to communicate with the correct port based on the hosts file, since typing the virtual hostname seems to return the page served by 127.0.0.2 (default) and not 127.0.0.2:80. So to me problem seems to be that its not talking to the correct port but I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your vhosts.config being included in the httpd.conf ?

`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` make sure there is no # in front of it

Comment: It has been included, thanks for answering though.